# Inserting non-list elements in a SwiftUI view

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am working on a SwiftUI page that consists of a table view with some rows but I would also like to have some non-cell elements in there. I am currently having some issues with this and I have tried various different avenues. I basically just need some elements in there that aren't wrapped inside a cell while still maintaining the tableview's grayish background. In my example below, I am trying to get an image right under the table rows.

Below is my code:

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    private var color = Color(red: 32/255, green: 35/255, blue: 0/255)
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section() {
                    HStack {
                        Text("AA")
                            .foregroundColor(color)
                        
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("B")
                            .foregroundColor(color)
                        
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("C")
                            .foregroundColor(color)
                        
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("D")
                            .foregroundColor(color)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("E")
                            .foregroundColor(color)
                        
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("F")
                            .foregroundColor(color)
                       
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("G")
                            .foregroundColor(color)
                       
                    }
                }
                
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Page"))
            
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "fallLeaves")
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Here are all of the scenarios I have tried that have been unsuccessful:

- **Scenario 1**: Adding a HStack with the image outside of the List. (What the current code shows) This does not get the image to show as the table view takes the whole view.
- **Scenario 2**: Adding the HStack with the image within the list block. This wraps the image around the cell like so

[image: image in cell]

- Scenario 3: Wrapping the list and the HStack contains the image inside a VStack. This is no good as it's basically like a split-screen with two different views. The table gets shrunk and has it's own scroll bar. Notice the scroll bar in the image below

[image: scenario 3 with vstack]

The ideal solution would look like this but I'm not sure what to try as I can't get it to look like this where it's all one continuous view and the image isn't in a cell

[image]

Comment: 1. Use a section footer. 2 its `Image("fallLeaves")` 3. By the sounds of it you don't want a HStack wrapping your image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'll let you work out the padding and the rounding.

```swift
    struct ContentView: View {
        private var color = Color(red: 32/255, green: 35/255, blue: 0/255)
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                Form {
                    Section(content: {
                        HStack {
                            Text("AA")
                                .foregroundColor(color)
                            
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Text("B")
                                .foregroundColor(color)
                            
                        }
                    }, footer: {
                        Image("fallLeaves")
                    })
                }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Page"))
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use place your component (event a page view) inside the cell.

What can be done;

1. Use a Section to have a good style when you initiate another cell (because we'll make the following one transparent)
2. Create a new Section
3. Place a / any view
4. Add `.listRowBackground(Color.clear)` to the new view; to see the background transparently.
5. Add `.listRowSeparator(.hidden)`to the new view; to remove the cell line below.

After these, you'll have a placed view with additional padding. If this is important, you can play with padding to catch 0 padding distance. Also, by changing the list style (for this second group) with these kinds of styles, `.listStyle(.grouped)`, you can get catch zero padding/spacing.

The footer solution can work for images, but when you need some texts, you'll see that it'll scale down the sizes. So instead of footer, my solution is to use a cell view and show it as a non-cell item;

Here is my change, which works (at least I think)

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    private var color = Color(red: 32/255, green: 35/255, blue: 255/255)
    // Just changed color to test my changes better.
    // private var color = Color(red: 32/255, green: 35/255, blue: 0/255)
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section() {
                    Text("AA")
                    Text("B")
                    Text("C")
                    Text("D")
                    Text("E")
                    Text("F")
                    Text("G")
                }
                //foreground color won't colorize the cell's bottom lines
                .foregroundColor(color)
                
                Section{
                    HStack{
                        // Use Spacer or another horizontal alignment
                        // I just tried with another image, you can place yours with full width and remove the Spacer() 's
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark.seal.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .foregroundColor(color)
                            .frame(width: 100)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                    // Not required for single items; but would be usefull, if you'll add more views or sections
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Page"))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

And here is why your methods won't work;

Scenario 1: Using VStack and HStack will split the screen into different scrollable. This is by design, In SwiftUI `List` element overrides Stacks and `ScrollableView`

[(Reference)](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126898)

Scenario 2: Same as Scenario 1

Scenario 3: Actually, this is the same as Scenario 1

You might try 3 things;

1. My solution, I don't see a major problem
2. Footer solution, which can work, but for some views, you will have problems
3. Determine a background color in `ZStack` and develop a custom button object which looks like a cell view (cons: non-native way and long time consuming work around)